# Opengl ES 2.0: Is there a way to use less resources to draw in-game background texture

Tags: android, textures, opengl-es2

1.Should my in-game background be drawn with my game loop renderer, or if

2.I don't want to draw my background image every frame in my main renderer since it could possibly be a heavy job while the game loop is running. Do I need to use a separate thread or some other method to achieve this?

FYI, the background should be able to scale and translate with zooming function, it should be flexible.

Comment: Might be worth noting that once the texture is in memory its just dumping raw data to the screen ... so what's the real overhead?

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have background rendered either way. OpenGL redraws the whole frame each time. So what does it matter for performance where are you drawing it from? :)

It does not matter, unless you are doing some heavy computations to generate the background on CPU.

What you probably do is just updating the background location each frame (position, scale, rotation), which is practically free. Doing that less often wont affect performance by more than 0.0001%. If it does affect performance - then you are doing something wrong or not describing the whole picture in your question.

Adding threads for this "free" task will just slow you down due to threads synchronization and cross-communication.

P.S. Always test your performance (that's called Profiling) before and after optimizations, you'll be surprised ;)

Comment: hope that doesn't surprise me alot~ :P

Comment: Seeing your assumption in the question makes me believe you will be surprised a lot :P

Comment: I think i will just adjust 1 matrix to control the 2 triangle that fill with my background texture every frame. Just like drawing other rectangle texture. Is that a good method to draw background?

Comment: That sounds right. Now if you render the background sprite each frame anyway, guess how expensive is it to update 1 matrix per frame compared to total many thousands-millions of computations  happening each frame?

Comment: given that the background texture already been loaded into (GPU?) in onSurfaceCreated(), it should be as u said that it wont consume much resources